# Histogram for list of elements python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, histogram

Does anybody know how I can make this

**Input**

Explanation: <2> is the first input and shows the number of next inputs lines -> if the first input is n all the input lines are n+1

```
2 
purple 11,yellow 3,pink 1 
gray 8,blue 10,pink 12
```

and the last 2 lines are my next inputs(the user wants to collect and save their n days of selling Crayons and get Histogram of their sales

into this

**Output**

I want to print the line number and its list of words with their number's histogram(the "*"s actually)line by line

```
1
purple ***********
yellow ***
pink *
2
gray ********
blue **********
pink ************
```

I don't have a problem with getting inputs I just don't know what codes I should write to print this output.

PS: I stored sales in a list

Comment: How your input lines are stored? In a list? What is the format?

Comment: @Corralien Yes I stored them in a list

Comment: Here are a few things you might find helpful:  `int("11") == 11`.  Also, `11 * "*" == "***********"`

Comment: @MichaelM. ahhhh okayyyy!! ^-^ two of them completely helped with my problem

Comment: @melody Once you reach 15 reputation, you'll be able to [upvote multiple posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to tell others that both were useful to you. Accepting an answer is optional (so never feel pressured about it), but generally encouraged to denote that your issue has been resolved. If you can't decide which to accept, you can choose one randomly or choose neither, it's up to you!

Comment: @MichaelM. it's kind of you to explain these things to me, I'm really grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use [`.split()` method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) several times to split the line by `,` and then to split every element by `" "`. Then you should print the color (first part of the element) with `*` * second part of the element. I used [f strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/), but you can just use `+` in the `print()`. Here is the code:

```
lines = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    lines.append(input())
# making a list "lines" with all lines

for j in range(len(lines)):
    print(j + 1)  # line number
    for element in lines[j].split(","):
        print(f'{element.split(" ")[0]} {"*" * int(element.split(" ")[1])}')  # color and stars
```

Hope that helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is strictly in this format, you can just use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions) to store all input lines, then [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate) over those input lines. For each input line, split by the `,` to get each item, then split each element by a space to get the name and the amount. Once you have the name and the amount, you can just use a `print()` statement and use string multiplication to repeat the `*` (asterisk) character `amt` times. Like this:

```
times = int(input())
lines = [input() for _ in range(times)]
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    print(i+1)
    for item in line.split(','):
        name, amt = item.split(' ')
        print(name, '*' * int(amt))
```

As [Corralien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien) mentioned in a comment, you could replace that last line to use an f-string if you'd like, however, it doesn't change functionality:

```
print(f"{name:8} {'*' * int(amt)}")
```

Comment: IMHO, folks who are asking what are obviously programming 101 homework questions benefit more from tips and tricks rather than full answers.  Especially considering that subjects such as "list comprehensions" are probably beyond...what is this, week 3 of spring semester or so?

Comment: You can enhanced your answer using f-strings: `print(f"{name:8} {'*' * int(amt)}")`

Comment: @Him I agree, but I also believe that without a full example or exposure to code, it can be very hard to apply those tips and tricks to practical situations (from my own experience, yours might differ). I've edited my question to include some links to Python documentation, which are fairly each to understand as a beginner and provide additional examples.